# Python - creating column containing the name of a team's opponent based on info in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (called "games") that contains a play-by-play list of a basketball games, where I record scoring streaks within single games (GameID identifies a specific game). The dataframe is sorted by matches (i.e., GameID).

Example of dataset "games":

```
    GameID  TeamID  Scoring Streak 
0   nbaG1     A        23     
1   nbaG1     B        12   
2   nbaG1     B        11   
3   nbaG1     A        24  
4   nbaG1     B        21 
5   nbaG2     C        15  
6   nbaG2     C        12 
7   nbaG2     D        17 
8   nbaG2     C        11
9   nbaG2     D        21 
10  nbaG3     E        10 
11  nbaG3     F        12  
12  nbaG3     F        14
```

From this dataframe I would like to simply create a column that displays the name of the opposing team within the respective match. For example in Game1 (nbaG1) it is Team A vs B. So, if Team A scores the new column "opponents" should say "B". However I have no idea how to scan for names within each game and return the value of the opposing team...nor have I found tips in other threads.

Desired output for my dataset "games":

```
    GameID  TeamID  Scoring Streak  Opponents
0   nbaG1     A        23              B
1   nbaG1     B        12              A
2   nbaG1     B        11              A
3   nbaG1     A        24              B
4   nbaG1     B        21              A
5   nbaG2     C        15              D
6   nbaG2     C        12              D
7   nbaG2     D        17              C
8   nbaG2     C        11              D
9   nbaG2     D        21              C
10  nbaG3     E        10              F
11  nbaG3     F        12              E
12  nbaG3     F        14              E
```

Comment: Can you send us part of your code for we can reproduce?

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha copy OP's dataframe and do `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"\s\s+")`

Comment: Thanks, Pranav Hosangadi! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general approach that would also work with more than two teams per game, you could use sets: First compute the set of teams for each game, then get the opponents for each row by computing the set difference between the set of teams and the set only containing the team itself.

```
teams_per_game = games.groupby('GameID')['TeamID'].apply(set)

opponents = []
for i in games.index:
    opponents.append((teams_per_game.loc[games.loc[i, 'GameID']] 
                      - {games.loc[i, 'TeamID']}).pop())

games['Opponents'] = opponents
```

Comment: Thank you Arne, this worked like a charme and returns exactly what I need, even for my big data set!

Answer (score 1):

First, group your dataframe by GameID and invoke `.unique()` to get the two teams that are playing the game

```
teams = df.groupby("GameID")["TeamID"].unique()

# game_teams :
GameID
nbaG1    [A, B]
nbaG2    [C, D]
nbaG3    [E, F]
```

Then, use this to look up both teams in each game and add the column to your original dataframe:

```
df["Teams"] = teams[df["GameID"]].to_list()

# df: 
   GameID TeamID  Scoring Streak   Teams
0   nbaG1      A              23  [A, B]
1   nbaG1      B              12  [A, B]
2   nbaG1      B              11  [A, B]
3   nbaG1      A              24  [A, B]
4   nbaG1      B              21  [A, B]
5   nbaG2      C              15  [C, D]
6   nbaG2      C              12  [C, D]
7   nbaG2      D              17  [C, D]
8   nbaG2      C              11  [C, D]
9   nbaG2      D              21  [C, D]
10  nbaG3      E              10  [E, F]
11  nbaG3      F              12  [E, F]
12  nbaG3      F              14  [E, F]
```

Finally, `apply` a function to each row that takes the element from `Teams` that is not in `TeamID`

```
def select_opponent(row):
    for team in row["Teams"]:
        if team != row["TeamID"]:
            return team
    return None

df["Opponent"] = df.apply(select_opponent, axis=1)

# df: 
   GameID TeamID  Scoring Streak   Teams Opponent
0   nbaG1      A              23  [A, B]        B
1   nbaG1      B              12  [A, B]        A
2   nbaG1      B              11  [A, B]        A
3   nbaG1      A              24  [A, B]        B
4   nbaG1      B              21  [A, B]        A
5   nbaG2      C              15  [C, D]        D
6   nbaG2      C              12  [C, D]        D
7   nbaG2      D              17  [C, D]        C
8   nbaG2      C              11  [C, D]        D
9   nbaG2      D              21  [C, D]        C
10  nbaG3      E              10  [E, F]        F
11  nbaG3      F              12  [E, F]        E
12  nbaG3      F              14  [E, F]        E
```

Comment: While your answer is exactly what the OP expect, I'm divided about having an odd number of lines. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Corralien I'm not sure I understand. Why does an odd number of rows matter, as long as each `GameID` has only two teams? I think your confusion stems from the fact that there are more than two entries per game (more than one per team per game).

Comment: @Corralien I'm not sure what OP's "scoring streak" represents, but if you replace it with "Scoring Player", for example, I think it'll make more sense: There can be an odd number of players scoring in a game, but that doesn't affect who the opponents were

Comment: Yes, you're probably right! +1 for your answer.

Comment: Thank you Pranav for this code, worked like it should and always returns the opposing team, alongside the list of teams per game :-) Just for clarification, the column scoring streaks lists the amount of unanswered points the respective team scored. So, for example in the first row Team A scored 23 points in a row, without any points of Team B. So indeed an odd number of rows is quite likely :-)

Comment: @Barrizzle why does the streak for game 1 go `A-B-B-A`? Is it because there was a break between the two `B`s?